# Why aren't all the images from a folder displayed on my tkinter label within a frame on a canvas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm writing a python tkinter script to retrieve .jpg files from a folder created by opencv and display all of them next to each other in horizontal fashion. I can get the code to work, in that, it displays jpg files next to each other. Howvever, after some frames,tkinter is placing one jpg file above other until the last jpg file. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. Below is my script. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
import os
import sys
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkFileDialog

path = 'C:\\JPEGs'
images = []

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        if '.jpg' in file.lower() :
            images.append(file)

images.sort(key=lambda f: int(filter(str.isdigit, f)))
#print images
## Main window
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720')
root.title("VIDYOANALYSER-Sachin Chandrashekar")
root.wm_iconbitmap('ad1.ico')
## Grid sizing behavior in window
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# Canvas
cnv = Canvas(root,bg="light yellow")
cnv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')

## Scrollbars for canvas
hScroll = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=cnv.xview)
hScroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
vScroll = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=cnv.yview)
vScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
cnv.configure(xscrollcommand=hScroll.set, yscrollcommand=vScroll.set)
# Frame in canvas
frm = Frame(root,bg="light yellow")


## This puts the frame in the canvas's scrollable zone
cnv.create_window(0, 0, window=frm, anchor='nw')
## Frame contents
columnCount=0

for files in images:
    im = Image.open(files)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    myvar=Label(frm,image = tkimage,text=str(os.path.basename(files).strip('.jpg')), compound=TOP,bg='sky blue',relief=SUNKEN)
    myvar.image = tkimage
    myvar.grid(row=0, column=columnCount, sticky='nswe')
    myvar.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    myvar.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    columnCount += 1



## Update display to get correct dimensions
frm.update_idletasks()
myvar.update_idletasks()
## Configure size of canvas's scrollable zone
cnv.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, frm.winfo_width(), frm.winfo_height()))

## Go!
root.mainloop()
```

Expected :There are 253 jpeg files  and i expect all the frames to be displayed. Check the link-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRMTy.png
Actual: Only 243 files are displayed and rest of the frames are displayed on above the other and only the last frame(half cropped) is visible on the UI.Check the link-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqMeL.png

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your code format is messed up. Please consider formatting it. Add backticks ``` before and after the code to format.

Comment: Are you sure about `int(filter(str.isdigit, f))`? This should throw an error `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'filter'`.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the response. I don't get any error. The script is running without any syntax errors. Just to let you know i'm running python 2.7

Comment: After removing `images.sort(key=lambda f: int(filter(str.isdigit, f)))` as it causes errors I can display all images. Cannot reproduce problem.

Comment: Ah I do see some overlapping after adding a large amount of images

Comment: Tk apparently uses 16-bit coordinates in some places, which means that the maximum area you can scroll is 32767 by 32767 pixels.  That's consistent with images that are about 134 pixels wide in your case.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that makes sense to me now. Is there any workaround for this problem? Im working on video analyser which can take a video file and analyse it. Longer file can have more than 30000 frames(jpegs).

Comment: I did just finish testing with 300 smaller images and I can see all of them. I tested with 600 images and I can see how after 371 they start to overlap all the way to 600 images. Though it looks like @jasonharper has the info you are looking for. Good to know that there is this limitation.

Comment: @Sachin to handle that issue you can measure the width of your images and then create either a new line after pixel length is met or create a list of list to switch to next section. Probably the list of list will be the best bet here.

Comment: Thanks @Mike-SMT for looking into it. You will hit the limit at some point depending the size(read resolution) of the image you are displaying.Not sure if this limitation is catered by any other programming languages? Many of the Video analysers i have used can display thousands of frame with no issues.

Comment: As jason mention it is due to the 16-bit coords. I imagine that PyQt would be your next best bet. From testing I can see my total pixel width of my images is 49200 with each being 82. The point where it starts to overlap is roughly 30504 and that is close to the coords mentioned by jason. If you account for the slight spacing between images I imaging we get close to that 32k pixel width.

Comment: Thank you Mike. Will update the thread on what i find with your suggestions.

Comment: One last idea that will keep you in tkinter. Store a list of images or list of image location and then as you scroll you can load the next image and delete the images that is no longer visible. This will take a bit more code but will allow you to keep working in tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jasonharper pointed out that tkinter uses 16-Bit coords in this case. *(not sure if this is the same for all containers)*.

I have modified your code to include some measurements so we can see how our total image size compares to total label size.

I added 2 variables:

```
total_image_size = 0
total_widget_size = 0
```

Then while creating all the widgets I check the size of each image and update `total_image_size`.

Then I loop through all widgets in the frame to get their width with `winfo_width()` and update `total_widget_size`.

We have to run this program twice however. The first time to see how many images are displayed before it starts stacking images and a 2nd time after updating the loop that counts the widgets so we get a close to accurate size of the widgets as we don't want to count the width of the stacked widgets.

With the below code you can see that the 16 bit coord limitation is accurate as the last widget to be place before stacking put the total width to 32736. If we take into account the small gap shown in the image below we can say with a high degree of accuracy that the limitation is spot on.

My test image measured at 82 pixels wide and the widget measured at 88 pixels wide per image/widget.

**Conclusion**:

for your needs just loading a massive list of images may not work here however if you use a list to store your images or image paths you can use a scale to scroll through them and load them into a from dynamically to get around this limitation.

**Results**:

[image]

**Code**:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


path = r'complete\file\path\here'
images = []
total_image_size = 0
total_widget_size = 0
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        images.append(file)

tk.Tcl().call('lsort', '-dict', images)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720')
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
cnv = tk.Canvas(root,bg="light yellow")
cnv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')

hScroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal', command=cnv.xview)
hScroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
vScroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=cnv.yview)
vScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
cnv.configure(xscrollcommand=hScroll.set, yscrollcommand=vScroll.set)
frm = tk.Frame(root, bg="light yellow")
cnv.create_window(0, 0, window=frm, anchor='nw')
columnCount = 0

for files in images:
    im = Image.open(files)
    width, height = im.size
    total_image_size += width
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    myvar = tk.Label(frm, image=tkimage, text=str(os.path.basename(files).strip('.jpg')),
                  compound='top', bg='sky blue', relief='sunken')
    myvar.image = tkimage
    myvar.grid(row=0, column=columnCount, sticky='nswe')
    myvar.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    myvar.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    columnCount += 1


frm.update_idletasks()
cnv.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, frm.winfo_width(), frm.winfo_height()))


def do_thing():
    global total_widget_size
    for ndex, widget in enumerate(frm.winfo_children()):
        if ndex <= 371:  # set the last image to be loaded before stacking started.
            total_widget_size += widget.winfo_width()
    print('Total widget width prior to stacking', total_widget_size)


print('Total image width', total_image_size)
# short delay so we can check size after all images have been loaded.
# If it takes longer than 3 seconds for your app to load then change this time to be more.
root.after(3000, do_thing)
root.mainloop()
```

Test imaged used:

[image]